# rendering data to react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

getting 40 errors of this using this componentdidmount not sure what it means already tried looking it up

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
  results: [],
  search: "",
};
componentDidMount() {
API.getRandomUsers()
// console.log(API.getRandomUsers())
.then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data.results }))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
};

render() {
return (
<div>
  <Navbar />
  <Form />
  <Wrapper>
  <Table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <SearchResults
     results = {this.state.results} />
  </tbody>
</Table>
  </Wrapper>
</div>
)}
```

Search results component

```
const SearchResults = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
<tr>
{props.results.map((employee, index) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <img alt={employee.results} className="img-fluid" src={props.src} />
      <td> {employee.name} </td>
      <td> {employee.phone} </td>
      <td> {employee.email} </td>
      <td> {employee.dob} </td>
  </tr>
)})}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in this part. Check where you are rendering. React does not render objects. You might be having something like this: `{results}`, but it should be something like `{results.title}` (assuming results is not an array, of course).

Comment: Looks like error is in `SearchResults` where you are passing your state array of objects. Can you include that `SearchResults` component code? You are likely iterating the array and attempting to render each object directly instead of rendering into JSX.

Comment: From where this `src={props.src}` is coming in `props` ?

Comment: I suspect it is your `employee.name` property is the object that has the `{title, first, last}` keys. Can you verify? You might just need to destructure those into a renderable name.

Comment: @DrewReese yes you are right it has the {title,first, last} keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The mapped `employee.name` is an object with the `{title, first, last}` properties.

## Solution

Here I usually dump these destructured values into an array and join them.

```
{props.results.map((employee, index) => {
  const {
    dob,
    email,
    name: {title, first, last},
    phone,
  } = employee;

  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <img alt={employee.results} className="img-fluid" src={props.src} />
      <td>{[title, first, last].join(' ')}</td>
      <td>{phone}</td>
      <td>{email}</td>
      <td>{dob}</td>
  </tr>
)})}
```

Comment: nice thanks.  can i do the same with the DOB joining the date and age?

Comment: @haroldParada Sure! Destructure then format/render however you need them to be displayed.